# Replace column values with other values in Hive

Tags: hive

I have 2 Hive tables, One is transaction table and other is master.

1st Hive Table-

```
1,London,UK
2,Dubai,UAE
3,W-DC,USA
```

And my master table is like

```
UK,Europe
Dubai,Asia
USA,N-America
```

And I want result like this:

```
1,London,Europe
2,Dubai,Asia
3,W-DC,N-America
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not support `update` from `join`.To achieve this you will have to use `insert overwrite table`.

Note: Make sure you test the `select` statement for the desired result before using it in `insert overwrite table`

```
insert overwrite table tablename
select a.col1,a.col2,b.col2
from tablename a join mastertable b on a.col3=b.col1
```